# Can CVS still be installed on NetBeans 8.0

Tags: java, netbeans, cvs

I have recently (Thursday 28th May 2015) installed Netbeans 8.0 on my machine only to find that CVS does not come included on it as standard. I have hunted around but have found nowhere and no way to install CVS on the package. I confess that I know nothing about NetBeans but I do have to have it *with* the CVS installation for versioning. Is there anywhere or anyway to do this please? And, before anyone tells me, I am not sure that it is used any more - Mercurial may have replaced it...

Comment: [As of NetBeans 7.1 RC1, CVS is moved from the standard distribution of the IDE to the Update Center.](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CVSSupport) You just have to install the plugin from the Update Center

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood, you mean Tools | Plugins... but I'm afraid that I cannot find it in there anywhere in any section, even after getting the latest version, etc.

Comment: It's there, under Tools | Plugins... | Available Plugins (in NetBeans 8.0.2), Name: CVS, Category Base IDE. Try to update the list with "Check for Newest" and also check the Settings tab, maybe some sources are disabled.

Comment: It could be that I'm on 8.0 and not 8.0.2 - I'll have a word with a few colleagues overseas... }:o(